# Бесконечный цикл при отправке JSON из сервлета

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlet

Пытаюсь отправить из сервлета данные в формате `JSON` с помощью

```
response.getWriter().write(JSON);
```

но попадаю в бесконечный цикл.

```
 String JSON = builder.toJson(Complete_map);
          
 response.setContentType("text/plain");
 response.getWriter().write(JSON);
```

`Complete_map` - `HashMap` из строковых значений.

Использую библиотеку Gson. Но что бы я туда не передал - всегда бесконечный цикл.

```
 function show_Value()
 {
function MapObject(name,value,mutter) {
    this.name= name;
    this.value = value;
    this.mutter = mutter;
}
$.ajax({

    url:'show_Registers',
    success : function(responseText) {
        var map = String.valueOf(responseText);
        var  p = JSON.stringify(map);
        $('#MyMap').text(p);
       setTimeout(500,show_Value());

    }
});
 }
```

Причем такая штука происходит только в Google Chrome, Opera и IE, данные в Ajax, видимо не приходят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это потому что у вас объекты имеют циклическую циркулярность. Обратите внимание, что вы не можете сериализовать объекты с круговыми ссылками, поскольку это приведет к бесконечной рекурсии.

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

(Serialization)
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj); 
==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```